Custom spring starter dependency in application throw Parameter 0 of method in required a bean of type that could not be found
I built a custom Spring Security starter, configuring a
Customizer<OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer<HttpSecurity>> rsCustomizer bean based on provided properties.
@AutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan("my.package.structure")
public class MySecurityAutoConfiguration {
} 

@Configuration
public class SecurityAutoConfiguration {

    @Bean
    Customizer<OAuth2ResourceServerConfiguration<HttpSecurity>> rsCustomizer() {
        return rs -> rs.someCustomConfiguration();
    }

} 

An application has a starter in dependencies, and build a SecurityFilterChain in a method annotated as @Bean, having an rsCustomizer bean wired as a method parameter.
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(final Customizer<OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer<HttpSecurity>> rsCustomizer,
                                            final HttpSecurity httpSecurity) {
    httpSecurity.cors(withDefaults())
               .csrf(disable())
               .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.anyRequest().permitAll())
               .oauth2ResourceServer(rsCustomizer);
    return httpSecurity.build();
} 

When I run an app locally on my PC, everything works fine and no errors appear, a filterChain gets registered and app is secured based on properties I provide.
But when I push it to kubernetes cluster, a method that has rsCustomizer bean as parameter throw 'Parameter 0 of method in required a bean of type that could not be found' exception, as like it cannot initialize on time.
I tried using @DependsOn("rsCustomizer") for SecurityFilterChain method. Tried @AutoConfiguration(before = Security AutoConfiguration.class) above starter main config class and security config class, where a bean is declared, together and separate both, tried @Lazy init for rsCustomizer, but all of them worls locally, and fails in kubernetes.
The only thing that worked is creating a method:
public Customizer<OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer<HttpSecurity>> getCustomizerBean() {
    try {
        return applicationContext.getBean("rsCustomizer");
    } catch (final Exception ex) {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        return getCustomizerBean();
    } 
}

and getting a bean like this.
Why can that happen and is it possible to fix it on starter side, without boilerplating workaround code in every project using a starter?
